# How can I loop imagick to show preview images of all pdf files in a folder

Tags: php, imagick

I have this code:

```
$im = new imagick($folder) . '[0]');
// convert to JPEG
$im->setImageFormat('jpg');
$im->resizeImage(290, 375, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
$im->setResolution( 700, 700 );
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $im;
```

My question is: How do I loop this result? Any time I loop, I get header issue.

Comment: You can't  "loop" in http output, sending a header, then content, another header and content.  Look around for information about creating a slide-show via http.

Comment: A sample code could help please?

Comment: This is what I want to accomplish: I have list of pdf files in a folder, I want to ceate a preview of all pdfs using imagegick - preview of pdf in images.

Comment: All the images on one page, or one per page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it. I used this method: In my loop, I called thumbnail.php as image source

```
<li><a href='download.php?pathname=$file'><img src='thumbnail.php?pathname=$file' style='float:left; margin-top:-10px; text-align:center; width:111px;' /></li>
```

Then on thumbnail.php I call my header and imagick, this way:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$im = new imagick($_GET['pathname']. '[0]');
// convert to JPEG
$im->setImageFormat('jpg');
$im->resizeImage(290, 375, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
$im->setResolution( 700, 700 );

echo $im;
```

Worked the way I like it!

Comment: But slow. I don't know how to make it fast. Any idea?